# How to format text for chat message when the message is sent via rest request

Tags: embedded-services, chatbot

We have implemented the chatbot in our org and also integrated it with our third party system via endpoint: '/chat/rest/Chasitor/ChatMessage'

Now when we are sending the request (message body in JSON) to the Salesforce chatbot via the above mentioned endpoint. Now since this incoming request contains the chat discussion between the auto chatbot and end user in that third-party system so this contains both conversation and when this whole conversation posted in Salesforce standard chat it shows in grey color. We tried to add some css in the request body itself to differentiate the chat between end user and the auto chat from third-party system but when the message landed in Salesforce chat bot it simply posted the message with applied css code instead of applying the color via that css. Can anyone please suggest if we can perform some format editing applied in JSON request itself so after posting the chat in Salesforce chatbot it will easily differentiate the chat posted as part of the request.

Comment: I would search for the Sf chat setting or contact Sf support for this. I am not sure you are supposed to set those CSS details in the JSON

Comment: Hi @BorisGichev , thanks for your response. Yes I understand , but instead of this do we have any other way to achieve this something via custom lightning component using with transcript.

Comment: Sorry I am not sure how to help here.